# How to `--reference` a local git repository in an existing checkout

Tags: git

When cloning from a remote repository with `git clone`, I can give git a hint with `--reference` that there is a similar local repository where some of the objects can be found, and shared in. This saves network bandwidth and storage costs.

But what if I already have two repositories, `a` and `b`, both cloned from remote. How can I achieve the effect in hindsight, so that `a` behaves as if it wasa cloned with `--reference=b`?

(This won’t save the bandwidth, but would free up some disk space.)

Answer (score 0):

Using only `git-command`, I would

1. Locally clone `b` to `c` (to reuse common objects with hard link, if possible).
2. In `c`, add `a` as a remote repo, and fetch the difference from `a`. Create needed branches and remotes in `c`.
3. Replace `a` with `c`.

Similar thing should be possible with linking common objects (`rsync --hard-link` or `cp -l`) and `git-gc`. I haven't a complete solution though.

Comment: Thanks, but I’d like to avoid such manoeuvres and leave the repository’s meta-data (branches, remotes, index, rebase in progress, whatever) and working copies untouched.

Comment: Maybe just linking files between 2 `.git/objects`.